Quarto inline fragments that don't break into boxes
In a Quarto presentation I'm trying to change the color of a portion of text inside of a single line, and in such a way that the fragments appear one after the other.  Here is my QMD file so far:
---
title: "Mathematical Reasoning"
format: revealjs
incremental: true
---

:::: {.fragment}

Consider the following paradoxes.  

::: {.inline-fragment}
<span style="color:gray">(or just curiosities)</span>
:::

::::


with the following added to reveal.css
.inline-fragment {
  display: flex;
}

inspired by this answer to a related question:  Using quarto and revealjs how can I have one word appear on a line on a slide?
(The reveal.css file is auto-generated by Quarto when a presentation is first rendered.  The full file is so long that I'm not able to include it here due to the character limit -- it's a very large file.  But for that reason I can't provide a complete working example of what I'm describing, so I have just describe that the above CSS is added to this auto-generated file.)
However, in my use case, this cases the stuff in the first fragment to line-break and form a text box.  The second fragment then doesn't render inline but instead in its own box next to the first box.
I'd appreciate if anyone knows how to make these fragments render as if they were written in a single line.

Do you need the .inline-fragment approach? Wouldn't using Consider the following paradoxes [or just curiosities]{style="color: gray;"}.  suffice?

@Jan Oh it might!  But without the .inline-fragment, wouldn't the whole line appear in a single transition rather than in two separate transitions?  I am hoping to make the stuff in the first fragment appear, and then later the stuff in the second fragment.

Okay, thank you. Then I understand what the issue is ...

@Jan You're right, I did not express it as clearly as I could -- I've edited to make my question more accurate.

You can use [your-text]{.fragment style="your-css"} like this:
---
title: "Mathematical Reasoning"
format: revealjs
incremental: true
---

Consider the following paradoxes. [(or just curiosities)]{.fragment style="color: gray;"}


